# Automate Windows From Button

Tags: asp.net, windows, forms

I am looking for a tool that helps me click a button in a windows form(ASP.NET) periodically.Any ideas??? Basically I depeloped a Web Form using ASP.Net (C#). There is a button on this form. I am looking for a tool that clicks on this button every 10 seconds automatically(For testing purposes)

Comment: Windows Forms is unrelated to ASP.NET. Which do you want to know about?

Comment: The term "windows form" has specific connotations to a windows application.  If you're using ASP.Net, it's called a "web form".

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you're trying to do, your question is somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it yourself. If it was a web page, you can read the contents of the webpage and fire the event as if you clicked the button every certain period of time you choose. I don't remember how it was exactly but I once did that by parsing HTTP from a website and doing the same functionality the website do through a windows Form application. Sorry I couldn't give you detailed answer more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Well!!! I think there are enough comments asking you to provide more information. But here is my part.

You can use any automated testing tools and record your activity once and then use the testing tool to click the button periodically.

This page [lists 420 testing tool](http://www.softwareqatest.com/qatweb1.html)s ;-) choose which you think suits your need.

Another option is to develop a .net windows application and call the button action web page periodically using a timer.

Hope this helps.